# How to select the value of the first ID in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @Good INT
 SELECT @Good = Good
   FROM MyTable
  WHERE DateDeleted IS NULL
  GROUP BY ID
 HAVING ID = MIN(ID)
```

In a stored procedure I wanna set a variable @Good. The conditions I need are that the `DateDeleted` is null and the minimum `ID`.

Example:

```
ID   Good   DateDeleted
-----------------------
1    5      15-12-2013
2    3      null
3    4      null
4    1      null
```

The result has to be 3

The error message I got is:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Column 'MyTable.Good' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What am I doing wrong?

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Good INT
Select top 1 @Good = Good
From MyTable
Where DateDeleted is null
Order by Id
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99f7d/1)

Comment: To add some explanation to this, the original query did not work because the selected column was neither aggregated nor listed in the `GROUP BY`-clause.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to have the good with the minimum ID which is not deleted.

I think it should look like this:

```
DECLARE @Good INT

SELECT  @Good = Good
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   ID = ( SELECT   MIN(ID)
               FROM     MyTable
               WHERE    DateDeleted IS NULL
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data provided we can get the desired value with the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @Good INT

 SELECT @Good = Good
   FROM MyTable
  WHERE Id =
        (
         SELECT MIN(Id)
           FROM MyTable
          WHERE DateDeleted IS NULL
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution could be

```
select @Good = Good
from MyTable 
where id = (select MIN(ID) from MyTable WHERE DateDeleted IS NULL)
```